# Error while disabling Redis API in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-api, google-cloud-memorystore

I am developing an app that uses redis as my secondary database to store users leaderboards as my backend I use firebase. To connect redis to my backend I used Google Cloud Memorystore for Redis API. I enabled this API and now I no longer need to have it enabled because it generate some costs. When I am trying to disable it I get error. [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlnM9.png).
The error message says:
Error disabling API
If Google Cloud Memorystore for Redis API has resources that are in use, deactivate them and try again.

I was trying to find this activated resources but I can't find any. I was trying to find any clues on [there](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/troubleshoot-issues) but I did't find anything that would help me.

Comment: APIs do **not** cost money. That means disabling an API will not save you money by itself. Only resources that you create are billed.

Comment: Use [Asset Inventory](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/asset-inventory/dashboard) in the Google Cloud Console GUI to see the resources you have created.